# Canonical reference of number of concurrent connections a web browser opens per domain

Tags: concurrency, connection, browser

I am interested in knowing how many concurrent connections various Web browsers will open per-domain.  For example, I realise that until circa 2008, many browsers would only open two concurrent connections per domain and that since then, perhaps six or more connections has become standard.  Is there any kind of canonical reference for this though, by both browser and browser version?  At the moment the information appears to be scattered across the Internet, and I haven't found much that addresses specific versions of browsers which change rapidly (e.g. Chrome and now Firefox).  Has anyone already compiled a listing somewhere of this information?

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to each of their documentations to find out. When I first heard about it in 2008, the standard across the board was 8. 4 had been the previous by IE as late as 2004.

Firefox I last heard initiated 16, fasterfox plugins allowed for 24-32 as the settings can be changed by user or plugin.

If you are asking this to find out about hosting beware of bluecoat proxy servers in use by many government, military, and utility firewalls. They allow pre-fetch and scanning and their admin's will often cluelessly configure their concurrent connections to 256 thinking it will go faster then.